# How to maintain the position of painted vertexes when appends new vertexes and edges with d3 force(canvas)?

Tags: d3.js, canvas

In a d3 force painted graph(the vertex amount is n), I will expand some vertex and get a new graph based on it(the new vertexes amount is m).I just wanna to maintain the position of painted vertexes (the amount is n), and make the position of new vertexes (the amount is m) and edges appropriately.

I have fixed the old vertexes when paints new vertexes, but not make the position of new vertexes (the amount is m) and edges appropriately.

Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-dijkstra-pjn55

I have trouble in this issue for a long time, your prompt reply will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, could you share your code?

Comment: HI, Mehdi. I have shared my code, thank you for your attention.